I am trying to send Email using gmail in ASP.NET C# account but always getting error
I am sending email using gmail and getting the following error.

Error sending email: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. 64.233.166.109:465

This is my code for sending mail:
using MailKit.Net.Smtp;
using MailKit.Security;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using MimeKit;
using MimeKit.Text;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class LocalMessageServices 
{
    private readonly EmailConfig ec;

    public LocalMessageServices(EmailConfig emailConfig)
    {
        this.ec = emailConfig;
    }

    public async Task SendEmailAsync(String email, String subject, String message)
    {
        try
        {
            var emailMessage = new MimeMessage();

            emailMessage.From.Add(new MailboxAddress(ec.FromName, ec.FromAddress));
            emailMessage.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("", email));
            emailMessage.Subject = subject;
            emailMessage.Body = new TextPart(TextFormat.Html) { Text = message };

            using (var client = new SmtpClient())
            {
                client.LocalDomain = ec.LocalDomain;
                await client.ConnectAsync(ec.MailServerAddress, Convert.ToInt32(ec.MailServerPort), SecureSocketOptions.Auto).ConfigureAwait(false);
                await client.AuthenticateAsync(new NetworkCredential(ec.UserId, ec.UserPassword));
                await client.SendAsync(emailMessage).ConfigureAwait(false);
                await client.DisconnectAsync(true).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("error sending email: "+ex.Message);
            throw new Exception("error sending email: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}

And my email configurations are
"Email": {
  "FromAddress": "***@gmail.com",
  "FromName": "My Name",
  "LocalDomain": "use-local",
  //HOST
  "MailServerAddress": "smtp.gmail.com",
  "MailServerPort": "465",
  "UserId": "*****@gmail.com",
  "UserPassword": "myAppPassword"
},

Can someone please figure out what I could be doing wrong? Or what are the possible problems what should be corrected?

All my code started working without changing anything when I changed my network.
The problem here turns out to be that the email traffic that I was sending was blocked on one network (May be the specific port or the Url used was blocked).
So if You are having the same problem, try checking from some different network, (try using your mobile's hotspot, or a friend's WIFI). In this way you can make sure that there is nothing wrong with the network.

use my code i have create two file

file create all credentials add
public class email_helper
{
static string smtpServer = "";
static int smtpPort = ;
static string smtpUser = "";
static string smtpPass = "";
 static string fromEmail = "";
 static string toEmail = "";
 static string subject = "Test";
static string body = "Test Body";
 public static void file()
 {
     EmailHelper emailHelper = new EmailHelper(smtpServer, smtpPort, smtpUser, smtpPass);

     emailHelper.SendEmail(fromEmail, toEmail, subject, body);
 }

}

craete send email
public class EmailHelper
{
private readonly string smtpServer;
private readonly int smtpPort;
private readonly string smtpUsername;
private readonly string smtpPassword;
 public EmailHelper(string smtpServer, int smtpPort, string smtpUsername, string smtpPassword)
 {
     this.smtpServer = smtpServer;
     this.smtpPort = smtpPort;
     this.smtpUsername = smtpUsername;
     this.smtpPassword = smtpPassword;
 }

 public void SendEmail(string fromEmail, string toEmail, string subject, string body)
 {
     try
     {
         if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fromEmail) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(toEmail))
         {
             Console.WriteLine("Error sending email: FromEmail and ToEmail cannot be empty.");
             return;
         }

         using (var client = new SmtpClient(smtpServer, smtpPort))
         using (var mailMessage = new MailMessage())
         {
             client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
             client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(smtpUsername, smtpPassword);
             client.EnableSsl = false;

             mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(fromEmail);
             mailMessage.To.Add(toEmail);
             mailMessage.Subject = subject ?? "";
             mailMessage.Body = body ?? "";
             mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;

             client.Send(mailMessage);
             Console.WriteLine("Email sent successfully.");
         }
     }
     catch (SmtpException ex)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Error sending email: SMTP Exception - " + ex.Message);
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Error sending email: " + ex.Message);
     }
 }

}


only first file add your email server credentials
use port different

I suspect that SmtpClient.EnableSsl needs to be set to true before attempting to send. It defaults to false.
correct but if i have set true then not send email ...?

I suspect that SmtpClient.EnableSsl needs to be set to true before attempting to send. It defaults to false.
Google's SMTP docs indicate that smtp.gmail.com requires a secure connection, and I see you're specifying port 465 (which is the SSL port for that server). If the SSL port doesn't work, you might try port 587 (TLS) instead. TLS is the replacement for SSL, and some (all?) SSL encryption algorithms are disabled in many modern OSes for security reasons.
